# Angular: Looping through an array

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Angular and firebase and I have an specific query which I can't loop it on my view and I got no error. It returns an object with an array inside with the data I want. I can print the data on my console, but when I try to loop it on my view nothing happens.

**component.ts**

```
 users: User[];

 constructor(private pipe: DecimalPipe, private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this._search$.pipe(
      tap(() => this._loading$.next(true)),
      debounceTime(200),
      switchMap(() => this._search()),
      delay(200),
      tap(() => this._loading$.next(false))
    ).subscribe(result => {
      this._countries$.next(result.countries);
      this._total$.next(result.total);
    });


    this.firestore.collection<User>('users').valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(users => {
        this.users = users;
        console.log(this.users);
        this._search$.next();
    });
  }
```

component.html

```
<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of users | async">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This how my data looks like:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**

this is my interface for user

```
export interface User {
  id: string,
  bio: string,
  birthday: string,
  createdDate: string,
  dollars: number,
  email: string,
  gender: string,
  isEnabled: number,
  isVerified: number,
  last_time_online: number,
  modifiedDate: string,
  mood1: string,
  mood2: string,
  name: string,
  name_filter: string,
  online: string,
  photoURL: string,
  status: string,
  unicoins: number
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: users type should be Observable<Array< User >>

Comment: can you remove `async` pipe with ngFor and try again?

Comment: Hi, I try it but I got the error:  Property 'users' does not exist on type 'UsersComponent'.

18       <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of users">

Comment: you can remove the `async` pipe and assign the `users` array to `[]` to start.  That way you won't get the undefined error.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call an `async` pipe on an array.

Assign the result of the call to a variable

```typescript
users$: Observable<User[]>;

 constructor(private pipe: DecimalPipe, private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this._search$.pipe(
      tap(() => this._loading$.next(true)),
      debounceTime(200),
      switchMap(() => this._search()),
      delay(200),
      tap(() => this._loading$.next(false))
    ).subscribe(result => {
      this._countries$.next(result.countries);
      this._total$.next(result.total);
    });

  this.users$ = this.firestore.collection<User>('users').valueChanges().pipe(
    take(1)),
    tap(users => {
    console.log(this.users);
    this._search$.next();
  });
}
```

In your html

```html
<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of users$ | async">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

See [this Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cmujzy), I have created a dummy AngularFireStore for illustration

Comment: I got the error: 'Observable<User[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'User[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.

91     this.users$ = this.firestore.collection<User>('users').valueChanges().pipe(

Comment: Please note the `$` sign after user$ implies an `Observable`. Declare a property `users$: Observable<User[]>`

Comment: I realy appreciate it. Thank's! I tried this, but I got this error: Argument of type 'Observable<User[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User[]'.
      Type 'Observable<User[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'User[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.